# How to transform a Promise into an Either?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a custom `Either` type in my Node/JS project and want to convert a `Promise` into an `Either` and I'm not sure how to deal with it:

```
const Either = {};

//Wrap existing promise into an either
Either.fromPromise = (promise) => {
  return promise.then(Either.right, Either.left);
};

Either.left = Either.failure = x => ({
  map: f => Either.left(x), //no-op: no mapping if "left" value
  fold: (l, r) => l(x), //apply "left" function to extract error value
});

Either.right = Either.success = x => ({
  map: f => Either.right(f(x)), //map only if "right"
  fold: (l, r) => r(x), //apply "right" function to extract success value
});

//Then trying to fake a promise and use it:
const p = new Promise((res,rej) => {
      setTimeout(()=>res(1),100)
    });

//What's the cleanest way to interact with the either at this stage?
const e = Either.fromPromise(p); //returns a promise
```

It seems `e` is a `Promise` and I can't simply do `e.fold(l => ..., r => ...)`. What is the best way to wrap the underlying *Promissory* code and get it cast into an `Either` that one can work with as transparently as possible?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you expect `e.fold(...)` to return here.

Comment: `e.then(Either => console.log(Either))` :/

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - if it's an error, execute the `l` function else the `r` function (for left and right values respectively) and return the result per the definition of `fold`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I had tried that and get an `undefined`

Comment: https://playcode.io/660829/ - is odd, should be getting `{
map:f map {...},
fold:f fold {...}
}`